# Getting values of JSON takes too long

Tags: php, json, api

This code needs 5 seconds to run, when I submit. What should I do for a better performance? First I used file_gets_content but that took even a bit more time.
I split the name as I need first name and last name to add it to the url. URL = URL + last name + first name.

```
<form method='post' action='index.php'>
  <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>

<?php

  /* This is how the URL should look like
  // $url = "http://api.suredbits.com/nfl/v0/stats/wagner/bobby";
  */
  $url = "http://api.suredbits.com/nfl/v0/stats/";

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $names = array();
    array_push($names, 'Bobby Wagner', 'Zach Brown', 'Mason Foster',
                  'Preston Smith', 'Josh Norman', 'Ryan Kerrigan',
                  'Earl Thomas', 'Richard Sherman', 'Chandler Jones', 
                  'Marcus Peters');

    foreach($names as $n) {
      $split_name = explode(" ", $n);

      $url .= $split_name[1] . '/' . $split_name[0];

      //get json
      $data = loadFile($url);
      $json_data = json_decode($data, true);

      echo  $n . ' Tackles: ' . $json_data[0]["defense"]["tackle"];

      //reset url
      $url = "http://api.suredbits.com/nfl/v0/stats/";

    }


  }

  function loadFile($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
  }
?>
```

Comment: You're doing 10 queries... this is what takes time. Try to do a single query manually (browser or terminal) to check why it is so long to respond.

Comment: Single query takes not even a second. But I do need multiple queries as I want to present multiple players. Maybe using AJAX load could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in PHP you're doing external requests, which means that by default you're tied to the time it takes for the target server replies to you. And then you actually do a request for each name. and this is depending your connection.

Just in case I've tested your code (only PHP part) as it can be seen here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/139050ebc5d12236ab5fa32165943ca4de027672

And this was the result:

```
Start (3.504753112793E-5)

Before request to Bobby Wagner (4.7922134399414E-5)
After request to Bobby Wagner (0.44589018821716)

Before request to Zach Brown (3.0994415283203E-5)
After request to Zach Brown (0.48834991455078)

Before request to Mason Foster (4.6968460083008E-5)
After request to Mason Foster (0.45868515968323)

Before request to Preston Smith (3.6001205444336E-5)
After request to Preston Smith (0.4740629196167)

Before request to Josh Norman (4.2915344238281E-5)
After request to Josh Norman (0.45651292800903)

Before request to Ryan Kerrigan (4.1007995605469E-5)
After request to Ryan Kerrigan (0.46689486503601)

Before request to Earl Thomas (4.0054321289062E-5)
After request to Earl Thomas (0.45992112159729)

Before request to Richard Sherman (4.1007995605469E-5)
After request to Richard Sherman (0.44616389274597)

Before request to Chandler Jones (4.4107437133789E-5)
After request to Chandler Jones (0.51626300811768)

Before request to Marcus Peters (4.1007995605469E-5)
After request to Marcus Peters (0.46067094802856)

Total (4.6739158630371)
```

You can see here that each request takes around half a second.
This is the issue, the only work around this is, if you can change the target service/server, allow a list of names instead 1 by 1...

Comment: Ty. As you said I found a new api with a list, which works fine now.